# ¿Cómo puedo incluir una librería externa Javascript en Angular4?

Tags: angular, animación

he estado trabajando en varios proyectos con angular y para hacerlos mas interactivos uso animaciones pero, las animaciones de angular a veces no me dan lo que necesito y me gustaria incluir librerias como GSAP pero no he podido. ¿ alguna idea de como hacerlo ?

Answer (score 1):

Para añadir una animación GSAP a una aplicación de Angular 2/4, sigue estos pasos:

1. Ejecuta `npm install –save @types/gsap`
2. Incluye a `gsap` en el componente o servicio, por ejemplo:

   ```
   var gsap = require('gsap')
   ```
3. Úsala, por ejemplo:

   ```
   var tl = new gsap.TimelineLite()
   ```

Un ejemplo, crea un archivo llamado: `animation.service.ts` y pon este código:

```
var gsap = require('gsap')

export default class Animation{
  let tl = new gsap.TimelineLite();
}
```

Espero que te sirva.